# Install a newer version of libpng

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, libpng

I want to export a c++ project that i started in Windows to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. The problem is that Ubuntu has libpng 1.2 installed and I need libpng 1.6.5 or newer so i manually compiled libpng 1.6.5 on my computer but eclipse cdt uses libpng 1.2 so my project doesn't work. I tried to uninstall libpng12-dev package and it worked but after a restart something happened and Ubuntu Desktop stopped working and I had to reinstall Ubuntu from scratch. How can I install libpng 1.6.5 over 1.2 without destroying anything?

Comment: I'd suggest to ask the same question [here](http://askubuntu.com/).

Comment: Already did that i'm not sure if this is a ubuntu problem or a programming one!

Comment: You can install this new library from source to a different folder (e.g.  in ~/mylibs/, having ~/mylibs/include, ~/mylibs/lib, etc.). Later on, when compiling your own code, point to ~/mylibs/. If you are using the Environment Variables to point to the paths where the libraries are installed, just make sure your ~/mylibs/ comes first the other paths.

Comment: Jut to add to previous comment, just google for "how to install library in my home" to see different suggestion on how that can be done

Comment: Extract the newest version of this lib to any folder and open it with the current version of the compiler you are using, then compile and build out this lib for both release and debug modes. If they give you the options of either a DLL or Lib then it is your choice which to use, just make sure to link them appropriately. Once you have a successful build, create an environment variable on your machine to point to the root of this folder. Then make sure to tell your IDE where this library resides using the environment variable and paths; for static lib copy this into same folder as your exe.

Comment: (...continued) Also make sure that you are building this lib with the same code generation flags that you are using in your project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that libpng 1.6.5 must be linked with -lpng16 not with the usual -lpng